# PHP login script doesn't work in IE8 or IE9

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a site using a PHP script to login the user. It works fine in most browsers, but IE8 and IE9 seem to be having trouble with the cookies. I've read a bunch of similar posts, but so far nothing seems to help. Any ideas as to where the problem is here? Details are code are below.

We are using this code for our login script: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

### Login Form

```
 <?php
    if($error == 1) echo "<p class=\"error\">Your Log in information is incorrect</p>";
    ?>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">

     <div class="form-group">
      <!-- <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label> -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" name="inputEmail1">
           </div>
           </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- <label for="inputPass1" class="col-md-2 control-label">Password</label> -->
             <div class="col-md-12">
             <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPass1" name="inputPass1">
              </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="login-content">
           <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default signin-btn" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.inputPass1);">Sign In</button>
             </div>
              </form>
```

### Process Login Page

```
<?php
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV COM NAV OUR STP"');
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.



if (isset($_POST['inputEmail1'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['inputEmail1'];
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

    exit($email);

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login success 
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
```

}

### Login Function

```
//checks login info against db
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, fname, lname, pass, salt, type_id 
        FROM users
       WHERE email = ?
        LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $fname, $lname, $db_password, $salt, $user_type);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 

            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {                
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $user_type = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_type);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user_type;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                                "", 
                                                                $fname . $lname);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                              $password . $user_browser);

                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Walls of code, consult => Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` if you're not already doing so.

Comment: wikihow should be the last place you should look for....anything

Comment: Hashing the password on the client does not add any security because the hashed password is equivalent to a plain-text password. See this question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/https-security-should-password-be-hashed-server-side-or-client-side

Comment: Re: my previous comment. This code is also hashing on the server, so it's not a security problem. But it is completely unnecessary and makes your login depend on javascript. It is also the source of the IE bug.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in the javascript. Basically IE8 does not allow changing the 'type' of a field and there was a javascript function that hashed the password and then put the value in a new field where it set the type to hidden. I just made the field already set to hidden and then it worked.